# Need Support when Editing Microsoft Office Documents with IT Hit WebDav

Tags: document, webdav, editing

I just Use AJAX Library from WebDAV library to start WebDAV in browsers other than IE with your information from

http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/opening_ms_office_docs/

And This is result:

**Microsoft Office 2013**
IE:Protocol ext  ==> ok

Chrome:Protocol ext ==>ok

FF:Protocol ext ==> ok

**Microsoft Office 2010**
IE:ActiveX  ==> ok

Chrome:Plugin2 ==>fault

FF:Add-on ==>ok

**Microsoft Office 2007 and earlier**
IE:ActiveX ==>ok

Chrome:Java applet2  ==> fault

FF:Java applet ==>ok

I can not run editing document when run in chrome (version 45) from Microsoft Office 2010, Microsoft Office 2007 and earlier.

**please support us to run on Chrome.**

I have attached my demo, please help me solve this problem:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/6kv2d8zcq47w9fj/TestWebDavHtml.rar

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you are using the IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library v5 or later.

**Regarding MS Office 2010**:
Make sure you have Microsoft Office 2010 SP2 or later installed. Also verify that you have all Windows updates installed. WebDAV components are updated rapidly and may fix some issues.

**Regrding MS Office 2007:**
In general MS Office 2007 and earlier are not supported any more by Microsoft. However you still can open documents using it:

1. Make sure you have all MS Office and Windows updates installed.
2. Make sure you have a latest WebDAV Ajax Library v5 or later, client protocol application installed and [web browser extension enabled](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/open-doc-webpage/install/).